# Batch file to add Java Cryptography Extension files to updated Java

Tags: windows-7, java, powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to automate the following situation on a Windows 7 workstation.

I use Java only for a single vendor app that requires the Java Cryptography Extension files to be placed in \security. However, everytime Java updates, a new folder is created referencing the build number of the Java and the JCE files have to be copied again into the new location.

I hoped JAVA might set an environment variable that pointed to the latest version, but it doesn't. The most it seems to do is update some SYMLINKS that point to the new version. However, since these are links to files, I don't think I can use them to move the JCE files.

My hope is to create a script that will grab the JCE files from a common location, discern the latest path for Java, and copy the JCE files into the proper place.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'll have to get the full path for you. However, it's something like c:\program files(x86)\Java\java18_###\jre\lib\security where '###' is the build number that changes with each update applied to Java. So the path does change with each Java update. Thanks.

Comment: The old folder and files get removed. The JCE files need to be copied anew into the security directory under the new build number parent.

Comment: I have a static folder somewhere else that contains the JCE files, yes. Java leaves pieces of the old build folder structure but not the relevant folders like lib and security. Honestly I don't know why the update leaves anything behind as the only place I can put the JCE files is under the new build number folder structure.

Comment: Thanks, mate. I wonder if something as simple as copy c:\pathtojre\*.* c:\program files(x86)\java\java18_???\jre\lib\security\*.* would work?

Comment: I think the cleanest way is to figure out the highest build number and copy the files into the required spot. Copying into every build numbered folder would also work and, yes, the files are small.

Comment: Hmmmmmm....  I like the interactive nature of asking for the build number, but I think I'd rather have it all just happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's a batch script that will find the Java folder with the highest version build number and then copy all files from your stage folder to the correct folder (with the highest version number only) as you need for the Java installed on your machine.

I also put some IF logic in there so if the `\jre\lib\security` directory does not exist, it creates it and then does the `COPY` command.

Save this to a text file and name with `.cmd` extension. You may need to run this as administrator as well as the `C:\Program Files(x86)\Java` folder may require administrator permissions to copy to it.

***Sample Batch Script***

```
@ECHO ON
SETLOCAL

SET StageDir=C:\pathtojre

CD /D %programfiles(x86)%\Java

FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F in ('DIR /B /AD /ON java*') DO (
    SET HighestNumDir=%%F
)

SET HighNumFullDir=%programfiles(x86)%\Java\%HighestNumDir%\jre\lib\security

IF NOT EXIST "%HighNumFullDir%" MD "%HighNumFullDir%"

COPY /Y "%StageDir%\*.*" "%HighNumFullDir%"
EXIT /B
::::GOTO EOF
```

Comment: WOW. Thank you. I'll check it out this weekend and let you know how it works.

Comment: It works! I had to make a couple of changes mostly due to my faulty memory of the paths involved but it works well. I know a bit of Python but batch scripts are a dark art. This is wonderful. Thank you.

Comment: Oh... there's no EOF label so that line always fails.

Comment: The `EOF` is `End Of File` so that just tells it to go to `EOF` so it's a dummy label. You can replace it with `EXIT /B` if you want.... Actually, I'll comment out the `GOTO EOF` and put in `EXIT /B` above. Glad it works for you and I appreciate the question as well, always up for a challenge.